# Enable FCM push notification to open app to foreground

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to open ionic 3 application when I tap on fcm based push notification to the foreground

```
payload = {
  notification: {
    title: 'New ' + event.data().type,
    body: event.data().body ? event.data().body : '' + comment,
    icon: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/naturehu-bf51e.appspot.com/o/fevicon%2Ficon.png?alt=media&token=d0dbfda7-710a-4bbb-97c9-62418ce6c530',
    sound: 'default',
    click_action:"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
  }
}
options = {
  priority: "high",
  timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
};
```

Help to open app to foreground now it is opening but sending back to background

Answer (score 0):

Your question is less information. Anyway Try below `payload`.

```
payload = {

        "content_available": true,
        "priority": "high",
        "notification" : {
          "body" : event.data().body ? event.data().body : '' + comment,,
          "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
          "icon": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/naturehu-bf51e.appspot.com/o/fevicon%2Ficon.png?alt=media&token=d0dbfda7-710a-4bbb-97c9-62418ce6c530",
          "title": 'New ' + event.data().type,
          "sound": "default",
          "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
        },
        "data": {
          "show_in_foreground": true,
        }
      }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but after using "data": {
          "show_in_foreground": true,
        } I am unable to send notification